# mysql select equal data with same date wise

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run a mysql join query fetching data from 3 tables.
Table 1: user
Table 2: Outtiming
Table 3: Intiming

I want to show same date data from outtiming and intiming tables with same dates.

**e.g: 2017-09-13 = 2017-09-13**

But I'm not getting data with same dates.

---

```
$query = "SELECT ur.username, ur.user_department, it.*, ot.*
FROM users ur 
INNER JOIN intiming it ON ur.staff_id=it.staff_id 
INNER JOIN outtiming ot ON ur.staff_id=ot.staff_id 
WHERE it.staff_id=".$employee." 
AND it.date >= '$startDate' AND ot.date <= '$endDate'";
```

**Result**

[mysql query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIOEA.jpg)

Comment: And whats your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an addition condition in your WHERE statement to check matching dates: `it.date = ot.date` . Full query:

```
$query = "SELECT ur.username, ur.user_department, it.*, ot.*
FROM users ur 
INNER JOIN intiming it ON ur.staff_id=it.staff_id 
INNER JOIN outtiming ot ON ur.staff_id=ot.staff_id 
WHERE it.staff_id=".$employee." 
AND it.date >= '$startDate' AND ot.date <= '$endDate'
AND it.date = ot.date ";
```